# How to find inserted TODO between two commits

Tags: git, todo

Is there a way to find where a specific string was inserted between 2 commits using git?

The closest thing I've come up to is:

```
git diff -STODO <commit1> <commit2>
```

However it also shows removed TODOs, which I would like to ignore.